# what should be structure of website to retrieve site information in telegram?

Tags: url, web, telegram

Some website retrieved information in telegram when send link and some website doesn't like this:
[image]

So my question is there any structure for website to load information in telegram ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph like Facebook, twitter, telegram, Skype and ...

As an example, the following is the Open Graph protocol markup for The Rock on IMDB:

```html
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: After that, Use [@WebPageBot](https://telegram.me/WebPageBot) to refresh Telegram's link preview server cache.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use meta tag with name description:

```
<head>
<meta name='description' content="some content"/>
</head>
```

Comment: telegram use open graph protocol so i think better way is **og** prefix.
another thing is telegram cache for fetching url information. if you try to change something in meta tag section of your website please use another article or post or every entity you want to share in telegram. also for cache problem you can use [http://bitly.com] and change url.